# state vuex store is not working properly-VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Why `$store` is not working properly?

I have code below:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      siteName: null,
      fileLogo: null,
      fileFavicon: null,
      setting: this.$store.state,
    };
  },
  ....
};
```

And the setting has value:

```js
{
  "setting":{
    "id":1,
    "Title":"Laundry Sepatu",
    "Short_Title":null,
    "Logo":"Site_Logo.jpg",
    "Favicon":"Site_Favicon.png",
    "user_id":null,
    "created_at":"2020-07-29T09:00:28.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2020-07-29T09:00:28.000000Z"
  },
  "user":{
    "user":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"admin",
      "email":"admin@admin.com",
      "email_verified_at":null,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null
    },
    "token":"2|BEVhUeO..."
  }
}
```

[image: output]

But when I change to:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      siteName: null,
      fileLogo: null,
      fileFavicon: null,
      setting: this.$store.state.setting,
    };
  },
  ...
};
```

The setting was null.

[image: output]

Comment: There could be several reasons for that, the most common one being the module (`setting`) is not [`namespaced`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing), unless confirmed otherwise.

Comment: As the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) said, you should use the `computed` to get `store state`. Like the below. ```computed: {
    count () {
      return this.$store.state.count
    }
  }```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I guess your initial state of `setting` was null and some time later you dispatch an action to update it. Your mutation might be something like:

```js
someMutation (state, setting) {
  state.setting = setting
}
```

When you commit `someMutation`, you just assign the new reference of `setting` object to `state.setting` property, not update the old reference.

So in your second example `this.setting` which hold `this.$store.state.setting` which hold the initial reference of state will not update.

To make it works properly, instead of using with `data` function, you should use with `computed` which will re-compute when its dependency changed.

```js
computed: {
  setting () {
    return this.$store.state.setting
  }
}
```

See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/s965uLqo/).

Or use with the [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) helper.